# How to store json from request directly into mongo database

Tags: django, python-3.x, mongodb, djongo

I would like to store json from request body directly into mongo collection without creation of specific model in django. I cannot create it because specific fields in json may change and new ones can be introduced, so I would like rather to store it as it is without this abstraction layer. Is it possible?

Comment: Use 'json.loads(data)' then insert into mongo. If you have unserialized objects you will need to serialize them before.